# How to make the use of sparks to process payment in PyroCMS module

Tags: pyrocms

I am developing a bidding system in PyroCMS version 2.2.0. I have to develop a payment module to process the payment. How can I make use of sparks to develop the payment class?

Comment: Please provide more information about exactly what you want to accomplish and what you have already attempted.

Comment: I have to develop a payment module to process payments from gateways like Skrill and Debit/Credit Card. I want to extend sparks library available in PyroCMS for that. I have to allow the users to buy the package from the applications by entering their payment details. Once detail is verified and validated, the amount of the package should be processed to the merchant account and the purchase action is completed.  I am stuck in the payment section.